# How to use sensor datas in another activity (Now it works well thanks to your help!)

Tags: android, sensors, android-sensors

(Now it works perfectly)I am new to android development and I have written an showActivity to show my result data from another class. In that class I implement a sensorEventListener and get sensor data. But when I want to display data in my showActivity, I get nothing to show. All the data is 0(or false) and I dont know what's wrong with my code. It's much appreciated if you can give me some advise on how to fix it. Thanks a lot.
This is my showActivity:

```
public class MapShowActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


public SensorUse mySensorUse ;
private TextView myText;
private Button myButton;
private Timer timer = new Timer();
private int count = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mySensorUse = new SensorUse(MapShowActivity.this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_show);
    myText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.orientation);
}

public void startTimer(){
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(detectNewOrientation, 100, 100);
}

TimerTask detectNewOrientation = new TimerTask(){

    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                myText.setText(String.valueOf(mySensorUse.getOx()));
            }
        });
    }
};

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mySensorUse.sensorRegister(MapShowActivity.this);
    startTimer();

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mySensorUse.sensorUnregister();
}
```

}

And this is my Sensor class:

```
public class SensorUse implements SensorEventListener{
private float[] accValues = new float[3];
private float[] magValues = new float[3];
private float[] orientationValues = new float[4];
private float[] resultRotationMatrix = new float[16];
public float ax;
public float ay;
public float az;
public float sumAcc;
public float ox;
public static boolean flag = false;
public boolean rotationMatrixGenerated;
private SensorManager mySensorManager;
private Sensor accSencor, magSensor;

public SensorUse(Context context){



}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION){
        accValues = event.values.clone();
        ax = accValues[0];
        ay = accValues[1];
        az = accValues[2];
        sumAcc = (float) Math.sqrt(ax*ax + ay*ay + az*az);
        flag = true;
    }
    else if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD){
        magValues = event.values.clone();
    }
    if (accValues != null && magValues != null){
        rotationMatrixGenerated = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(resultRotationMatrix,
                null, accValues, magValues);
        if(rotationMatrixGenerated) {
            SensorManager.getOrientation(resultRotationMatrix, orientationValues);
            ox = (float) Math.toDegrees(orientationValues[0]);
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}

public void sensorRegister(Context context){
    mySensorManager = (SensorManager) context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    accSencor = mySensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION);
    magSensor = mySensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
    mySensorManager.registerListener(this, accSencor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    mySensorManager.registerListener(this, magSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
}

public void sensorUnregister(){
    mySensorManager.unregisterListener(this, accSencor);
    mySensorManager.unregisterListener(this, magSensor);
}
public float getAx(){
    return ax;
}
public float getOx(){
    return ox;
}
```

}

Comment: what`s the type of data you get from sensors? string?float?

Comment: Its floats, all sensors give an array of up to 3 floats.  Is onSensorChanged being called?  If not, its a problem with registering for the sensors.  If so, its somewhere in your update code for the screen which you aren't giving us.

Comment: THe one place you are setting the text is in onCreate.  You haven't even registered for the sensors there, much less gotten a value from them.  So of course it will be 0 then.

Comment: Aside from adding a sensorManager like the answer below, you shouldnt access a variable in a class directly, since the variable is changing so rapidly. Add a getter method to your class for that variable.

Comment: @GabeSechan Thanks a lot! So you mean that I can get my sensor data if I  try to put setText in onResume() method after registering sensors?

Comment: You'll have to wait for the sensor to actually pass you some data.  Really it ought to be done by onSensorChanged triggering the Activity to check the values.

Comment: @GabeSechan I get understand now and will try to find a way to fix it. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @SoroushA Thank you for your advice!

Comment: Like I said, you need to write after onSensorChanged is called.  Here's the timing that will happen.  onResume will be called.  Then maybe half a second later, onSensorChanged will be called for the first time.  That's when you have to set the text.

Comment: @GabeSechan Thanks a lot ! Now it works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

App doesn't know which class will be handling the sensor data.

You have to register your sensor class (SensorUse) object
to get accelerometer data.

Find example code below:

```
sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
senAccelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
sensorManager.registerListener(mySensorUse, senAccelerometer , SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

1. sensorManger is object of SensorManager
2. mySensorUse is class that has implemented SensorEventListener

Comment: Thanks for your help! But I think I register it in the sensorRegister() method. :)